# Memory usage and garbage collection of Objects in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, garbage-collection

I want to know about the `Object` type specifically when it comes to garbage collection in Flash.

I know that items will be ready for garbage collection in situations like this:

```
// create
var ar:Array = [];

var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.addEventLisntener(blah, blah);

ar.push(mc);
addChild(mc);

// kill & gc
ar.splice(0, 1);
mc.removeEventListener(blah, blah);
removeChild(mc);
```

But how/will an `Object` get garbage collected in situations like below.

Say I have a function in my class `MartysMC` that I parse an `Object` through:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class MartysMC extends MovieClip
    {
        /**
         * Updates this
         * @param obj An object containing key/value pairs to represent new property values
         */
        public function update(obj:Object):void
        {
            var i:String;
            for(i in obj)
            {
                this[i] = obj[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now I make use of this function like so:

```
var mmc:MartysMC = new MartysMC();

var dataObject:Object =
{
    x: 10,
    y: 34,
    alpha: 0.6
};

mmc.update(dataObject);
```

What happens to `dataObject`? Will this get garbage collected from here? Even still, what about the object in this line:

```
mmc.update({x:15,y:18,name:"marty"});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what happen with the GC you can use a [Dictionary](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) with a weak reference set to true and using the object you want to cheeck as a key:

```
var d:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true)
d[myObject] = whatever
```

when the object will not be longer available it will be delete from the dictionary.

here a complete sample based on your example at wonderfl :
http://wonderfl.net/c/e9W4

you see that very quickly both of your object have been garbage collected.

Comment: Cool, Dictionary can be used to monitor memory leaks this way!

Answer (score 2):

In your example, temporary object is created, passed into function, iterated by its properties, then it should be collected on next GC pass. There's nothing to hold it in memory (although GC pass may not come immediately, but there is no way (yet) to know that for sure.) If you're in doubt, I'd add that property access (`obj[i]`) creates no references to temporary object - property is just copied (basic types by value, and for classes reference is copied.)

Comment: So the only time a reference would prevent another object from being collected would be if the object itself is stored as a property of another object? For example, mmc.someObject = obj would then prevent the temporary obj from being collected? The GC is my weakness in flash.

Comment: Can you recommend any ways to test this? ie maybe something that will alert me when dataObject no longer exists?

Comment: @Ascension Systems: yes, exactly. GC references are one way - you can hold them to (former) object contents, while holder object is gone.

Comment: @Marty Wallace: If you're using FB, it has memory profiling tool. Create a lot of such objects and take couple of memory snapshots to compare. It probably can't be tested with pure ActionScript.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have Flash Builder; I work with the Flash IDE.

Comment: Then you only have options like DeMonster Debugger or similar to track free memory. Or just `new Stats()`: https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats