# AS3: Major Slowdown

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-leaks

I'm working on a Flash game, and after running my game for a while there is a huge drop in frame rate. There aren't a lot of MovieClips onscreen at once, but MovieClips are being replaced using removeChild and addChild often.

How can one test for problems such as memory leaks? And what are some good AS3 programming standards on this matter?

Comment: It's possible you haven't prepared your MovieClips for garbage collection properly. Are you removing all event listeners and reference to the MovieClips?

Comment: Actually, I am not removing listeners. I assumed removeChild would automatically remove listeners added to the MovieClips. This seems like it could be the problem.

Comment: Nope event listeners will halt GCing of an object. Not all objects are display objects but all objects can dispatch events. So in your case a data class that never gets added to the stage would be GCed. See how that would be a huge failure? Remove event listeners to GC an object, and of course any children objects will need it also.

Comment: Also make sure you remove your MovieClips from any Arrays they've been added to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're not preparing your instances of `MovieClip` for garbage collection. **[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197639/memory-usage-and-garbage-collection-of-objects-in-as3)** could be extremely helpful to you.

Some of the basic things you want to cover when discarding a MovieClip (or any other Object) properly are:

1. Remove the object from the `DisplayList` (if it's a `DisplayObject`). This is done via what you're doing already, `removeChild()`
2. Remove any event listeners that have been applied to the Object. Best thing to do is keep on top of this right from the beginning; by that I mean, when you call `addEventListener()`, be sure to somewhere in the very near future add a sister `removeEventListener()` as well.
3. Remove reference to your Object. This includes, but is not limited to: reference to the Object via being part of an Array/Vector, reference via being stored in a property of another Object, etc.

A suggestion that I can offer is to have in the base class of your objects a method that handles all of this, eg `remove()` or `deconstruct()`.

Here's an example:

```
public function deconstruct():void
{
    if(parent)
        parent.removeChild(this);

    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _onClick);
}
```

And when you extend this class and need other dereferencing features, just build on your `deconstruct()` method:

```
override public function deconstruct():void
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, _mouseOver);

    var i:int = someArray.indexOf(this);
    someArray.splice(i, 1);

    super.deconstruct();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://gskinner.com/talks/resource-management/